# Flutter navigator not working : OnPress not showing second screen

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code don't know why its not moving to screen 2 on button press:

Am beginner in dart/flutter please help. On press of button it's not showing screen2

//main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'screen_1.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Screen1(),
    );
  }
}

//screen_1.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screen_2.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen 1'),
      ),
      body: Container(

        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.pink,
            child: Text(
              'Go to Screen 2',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Screen2();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//screen_2.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text('Screen 2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Go Back To Screen 1'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

onPressed of Screen1 class should show Screen2 but it's not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it does move to Screen2:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Screen1(),
    );
  }
}

//screen_1.dart

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Screen 1'),
      ),
      body: Container(

        child: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.pink,
            child: Text(
              'Go to Screen 2',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Screen2();
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//screen_2.dart 

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text('Screen 2'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text('Go Back To Screen 1'),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This may be because `StatelessWidget` is part of material.dart yet you failed to import it in the first dart file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I may have missed to add import statement in my question. Able to compile & run the code & I can see button Go to Screen 2 but when I click on it it does not show screen 2.